# Can't delete record from MySQL database using PHP and HTML Form

Tags: php, mysql, sql, forms, sql-delete

I'm trying to create a form on a webpage, which takes an id number entered by the user, and deletes the corresponding record in a database. I'm unable to get it working.

This is the delete code which isn't working:

```
<?php 

    if (isset($_POST['deleteSubmit'])) { 

        $details = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['deleteNum']); 
 
        $deleteSQL = "DELETE FROM userName WHERE id = '$details'"; 
 
        $result = $conn->query($deleteSQL); 
     
        if (!$result) { 
            echo 'Error!';
            exit($conn->error); 
        }  else { 
            header('Location: index.php'); 
            exit; 
        }
    }

?>

<h4>DELETE NAME (DELETE)</h4>

<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">
  <label for="num">Enter User Reference to be Deleted:</label><br>
  <input num="deleteNum"type="number"><br>
  <input num="deleteSubmit" type="submit" value="Delete">
</form>
```

For reference, this is the post code which is working (it's being used to add names to the database):

```
<?php 

    if (isset($_POST['nameSubmit'])) { 
        $details = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['newName']); 
 
        $insertSQL = "INSERT INTO userName (name) VALUES ('$details')"; 
 
        $result = $conn->query($insertSQL); 
     
        if (!$result) { 
            echo 'Error!';
            exit($conn->error); 
        }  else { 
            header('Location: index.php'); 
            exit; 
        }
    }

?>


<h4>ENTER NAME (POST)</h4>

<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">
  <label for="fname">Enter Name:</label><br>
  <input name="newName"type="text"><br>
  <input name="nameSubmit" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

The database connection file is being called in both programs and is working for the post.php element, which is why I haven't included it or reference to it.

The database has one table called *userName* which contains two columns *id* (which is auto incremented) and *name*.

I've tried changing some of the syntax on the delete.php file with no success. I've ran the $deleteSQL code directly in my database and it works.

I see no error messages when enter an id and click the delete button.

Comment: besides using **prepared statements with parameters** to **prevent sql injection**, what happens when you runt the code directly on phpmyadmin

Comment: (1) Change `num="deleteSubmit"` to `name="deleteSubmit"`  (2) change `num="deleteNum"type="number"` to `name="deleteNum" type="number"` (3) Please use paratemerized prepared statement in your queries

Comment: @KenLee this has fixed the problem. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who reads this in future, the query was solved by @kenlee;

(1) Change `num="deleteSubmit"` to `name="deleteSubmit"`

(2) change `num="deleteNum" type="number"` to `name="deleteNum" type="number"`

(3) Please use `paratemerized prepared statement` in your queries